# Who have to screencast for Facebook approval?

Tags: facebook, api, screencast

I'm using Facebook api to post news on my page.

The process is as follow :

1. Edit the news on my website
2. Put the news on a pool, waiting to be published on my  Facebook page
3. A cron is runing and take one news from the pool and post it on my Facebook page.

I'm not using any Facebook's button, everything is done in the background.

So do I have to make a screencast for Facebook approval ? (If yes I really don't know how to make it)

Someone can help please ?

Answer (score 0):

> So do i have to make a screencast for Facebook approval ?

In general, that depends - on whether you are able to grant all necessary permissions, when your app is in “live” mode.

You are going to need `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions for this. For newer apps, Facebook does not allow to grant `publish_pages` any more, when the app is “live”, but the permission has not been approved yet in review - even for users with a role in the app.

So you will need to submit for review and get this approved, otherwise you won’t be able to grant this permission in live mode. (Your app needs to be in live mode; in dev mode all content created through it would only be visible to people with a role in the app, but hidden from normal users - not what you want.)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps gives instructions on how to submit an app that does not have a normal, public facing login implementation.

Make sure to describe to them very clearly that this app is not for public use.